# Gerar um número inteiro a partir da sequencia existente em outro numero inteiro, com Python

Tags: python, lista

Para chegar nesse resultado, eu pensei em começar transformando a str em int, criando uma lista com os elementos sequenciais. No entanto, não sei como fazer nos casos em que o número de entrada possua mais de uma sequência.

Por exemplo, uma entrada 123687 irá retornar (1, 2, 3), ok.

Mas, no caso de uma entrada 123965678, ele irá retornar (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7,8), sendo que eu gostaria de gerar listas separadas para cada sequência.
Logo, uma lista (1, 2, 3) e outra (5, 6, 7, 8).

Por fim, irei transformar isso numa função que retorne apenas o inteiro com a maior sequência.

```
numero = input('Digite um número inteiro: ')
lista = [int(i) for i in numero]
for i in range(len(lista) - 1):
    if lista[i] == lista[i + 1] - 1:

        sequencia.append(lista[i])
        sequencia.append(lista[i + 1])
    
print(list(set(sequencia)))
```

Comment: 1. Porque ```set``` no print() final?
2. Qual deve ser o resultado de ```2567```?

Comment: O set é para excluir os repetidos. O resultado de 2567 seria `[5, 6, 7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é iterar pelos dígitos do número inserido pelo usuário e utilizar uma lista auxiliar para fazer a análise da entrada e assim identificar sequencias de números naturais consecutivos menores que dez segundo o seguinte algoritmo:

Dada uma string como entrada cujo os caracteres sejam dígitos decimais

1. Armazene a entrada do usuário como uma string na variável `numero`.
2. Defina uma lista auxiliar chamada `lista`.
3. Defina uma lista chamada `sequencias` contendo os resultados a serem retornados ao fim do processo iterativo.
4. Do primeiro digito a esquerda da entrada até o último digito a direita faça:

- Verifique se a entrada foi esgotada:

  - Se sim verifique se há mais de um elemento na lista auxiliar `lista`:

    - Se sim adicione uma cópia da lista auxiliar a lista `sequencias` contendo os resultados.
  - Retorne o lista `sequencias` como resultado.
- Retire um dígito a esquerda da entrada.
- Verifique se a lista auxiliar não está vazia e verifique se o dígito extraído não seja o digito consecutivo ao último digito da lista auxiliar.

  - Caso as duas afirmações anteriores sejam verdadeiras

    - Verifique se há mais de um elemento na lista auxiliar.

      - Se sim adicione uma cópia da lista auxiliar a lista `sequencias` contendo os resultados.
    - Esvazie a lista auxiliar.
- Adicione o dígito extraído a lista auxiliar.
- Reitere o processo.

O algoritmo pode ser implementado usando um laço de iteração ou função recursiva, no caso preferi o implementar por meio de uma função recursiva e a implementação não faz nenhuma validação da entrada do usuário:

```python
numero = "12396567899456789345"#input('Digite um número inteiro: ')

def verificador(numero, lista=[], sequencias=[]):
    if len(numero) == 0:
        if len(lista) > 1:
            sequencias.append(lista.copy())
        return(sequencias)
    digito = int(numero[0])
    numero = numero[1:]
    lista = lista
    if len(lista) != 0 and lista[-1] != digito - 1:
        if len(lista) > 1:
            sequencias.append(lista.copy())
        lista.clear()
    lista.append(digito)
    return verificador(numero, lista, sequencias)    
  
print(verificador(numero))
#[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5]]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Recursiva#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pelo ensinamento, Augusto. Funciona perfeitamente!